# Ckeditor does not change text correctly in mvc

Tags: model-view-controller, ckeditor

I want to create rich text editor in admin panel.I write this code for creating
post.My model class is Post.cs and description property is that property i want use with ckeditor.

```
public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(5000, MinimumLength = 250)]
        [AllowHtml]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public List<PostImage> PostImages { get; set; }

    }
```

In My controller folder in main controller class my actions:

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            if (Session["Id"]!=null)
            {
                return View();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Login","Admin");
        }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Create(Post post,HttpPostedFileBase postImage)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("Create", post);
        }
       ....
```

And ckeditor display text but when details page show text it display like that

[In index page ckeditor display text ugly like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDJoj.png)

but I dont want ckeditor display this text to user like that.How can resolve this problem.
I change `config.js`,i search in google and watch video in youtube.
But I did not find helpful video or aarticle for me.
Can anyone knows how solve this problem?